# Python VS Excel - extract values

Tags: python, excel, client, extract

I want to extact values from excel per client using python. Meaning, I'd like to input the client's name (I have an excel report with different data from  different clients) and then retrieve some of the data from THAT one client (on another excel sheet)  - not sure what library / module / functions I should use ? Many thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas sounds like a good fit here. You can read the excel sheet into a dataframe and then when you get your input name you can select the row of data for that name